# How to find the time of being stationarity in time series in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, statistics

I have different time series of signals that each of which has a different shape. By applying ADF and using the null hypothesis also using P-value I could understand that my signals are stationary but I wanted to know from which time step, the signal became stationary. I mean the coordinate of the point in my graph which says from this point your time series is becoming stationary. I could write down the code to determine the condition but I was not able to recognize the time. I will appreciate it if you do this by exemplifying it.

```
from __future__ import division
import sys
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller

root = r'/home/hossein/Desktop/Out/NEW SCENARIO/BETA 15'
mean_curv=[]
my_list = os.listdir(root)
my_list =  [file for file in my_list if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(root, file))]
for directory in my_list:
    CASES = [file for file in os.listdir(os.path.join(root, directory)) if file.startswith('config')]
    if len(CASES)==0:
        continue
    maxnum = np.max([int(os.path.splitext(f)[0].split('_')[1]) for f in CASES])
    CASES = ['configuration_%d.out' % i for i in range(maxnum)]
    mean_curv=[]
    for i, d in enumerate(CASES): 
        a = np.loadtxt(os.path.join(root, directory,d)).T 
        num = os.path.splitext(d)[0] 
        local_curv = np.abs(a[4])
        mean_curv.append(np.mean(local_curv))
        pdf = stats.norm.pdf(mean_curv)
#print(mean_curv)
    result = adfuller(mean_curv) 

    print('ADF Statistic: %f' % result[0])
    print('p-value: %f' % result[1])
    print('Critical Values:')
    for key, value in result[4].items():
        print('\t%s: %.3f' % (key, value))

    Time = np.arange(0,len(mean_curv))
    plt.plot(Time,mean_curv,label=directory)
```

The results related to stationary has been shown down.

```
ADF Statistic: -5.843660
p-value: 0.000000
Critical Values:
    1%: -3.437
    5%: -2.864
    10%: -2.568
```

I have seen the examples of finding out that the time series is stationary but for sure it is possible to distinguish the location of stationarity.
[EXAMPLE](https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-data-stationary-python/) implies the condition to have a stationary signal or non-stationary time series. Based on the information which has been written here I can understand by splitting my signal to different parts and checking the statistics of the parts, it is possible to understand the time of stationarity. How about the automatic method, is there anything to do?

Comment: Please, share some sample data to make your question reproducible.

Comment: @Suthiro for this aim, you can use whatever data that you have, like passenger data for airline companies that increase in time [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/airline-passengers.csv)